# Rails: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting an error saying I'm not passing an ID when I'm trying to destroy a `Feature`, but I'm doing this using a `set_feature before_action`!

**Full error:**

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Extracted source (around line #63):

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_feature(params)
      @feature = Feature.find(params[:id])
  end

Rails.root: C:/Users/Nick/Amnesia_Rails/Master

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/apps/elements/features_controller.rb:63:in `set_feature'
Request

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"0Z/SxhhEO6OA6eiShd+1PZI0DQ9QK1I7G8wqoInz+vM=",
 "element_id"=>"3",
 "id"=>"5"}
```

**The show views:**

```
    <% @app.elements.each do |element| %>
      <tr>
          <td><b><%= element.name %></b></td>
          <td><b><%= element.description %></b></td>
          <td><b><%= link_to "Remove", [@app, element], method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?" %></b></td>
      </tr>
      <% element.features.each do |feature| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= feature.name %></td>
            <td><%= feature.description %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Delete", [element, feature], method: :delete %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>

          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to 'Add a Feature', new_element_feature_path(element) %></td>
          </tr>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

**The destroy and private methods:**

```
  def destroy
    @feature = Feature.find(params[:id])
    @feature.destroy
    @element = Element.find(params[:element_id])
    redirect_to(@element.app)
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_feature(params)
      @feature = Feature.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'm quite lost!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 0 for 1 is pretty clear for you.

```
def set_feature(params)
end
```

That's wrong.   (params) is your 1.   If you aren't passing something to it, that's 0.   And you're not.

Just make your before_action this:

```
def set_feature
  @feature = Feature.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The before_action isn't going to pipe in the params magically.

I think you should be able to access "params" without having it as an parameter of set_feature.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob, so I apologize, but could you please explain what you mean in a bit more detail?

If you mean to say that I should `@feature.destroy(params[:id])`, I've already tried that unfortunately to no avail :/ I just end up getting the same no arguments error.

Comment: I meant, when you write before_action :set_feature, it's just calling set_feature(), when you're specifying it as requiring one parameter.

Comment: So what `parameter` should I call in the `before_action`?

Comment: I've figured it out. I just removed `:destroy` from the `before_action`, but I don't quite understand why this works yet. Any links to help explain the why to me?

Comment: Yes, it seems odd to me too. But it's working flawlessly.

https://github.com/nickdb93/amnesia/commit/0aaa53465cc4aad2f0e0ce40c4bcdc3d1d66ea6e

Comment: Uh, because you took the before_action off of the method.

Comment: Change "set_feature(params)" to "set_feature".

Comment: Thank you! In hindsight, I'm not even really sure why I was passing params since I wasn't defining those params anywhere. I must've copied them from one of my other controllers and convinced myself that it was there for a reason.